# How to use C++ to Copy A Directory

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory, copy

I have made a backup program using c++, but it uses the System() command to batch copy files.

I am looking for a way to copy an entire directory (this does not need to create any directories, just copy them). Or alternatively, copy everything within a directory.

For example, I want to copy `C:\Users\ to E:\Backup\ Or C:\Users\* to E:\Backup\`.

If possible could you include an example in your answer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or C++11? Or is a Windows-only solution acceptable? There is no C++03 standard solution.

Comment: A windows only solution is fine!

Comment: Not sure that works on windows 8?

Comment: If you really want to back everything up with ACLs and such info I don't think that you can easily write a better program than `robocopy /b`

Comment: I will have a look at that, how would you suggest integrating robocopy?

Comment: Fast Google revealed some C# examples, they are using CreateProcess to start `robocopy` which it not really nice either. If you use this be sure to read the manual of `robocopy` first though. If you really want to do the copy in a C++ way, I'd recommend @harper's link or `boost::filesystem` as well.

Comment: @LiamPufferfishDaly If it needs to work on Windows 8 put that in your question and tag it.

Comment: @PeterWood I think a simple Windows tag would be enough. Also you could put in the question the compiler you're using.

Comment: Why does `system("xcopy /s C:\\Users E:\\Backup");` not work.

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 10):

As of today, C++17's [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) is the proper solution.

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::copy("C:/Users/", "E:/Backup/");
}
```

The slashes (`/`) are interpreted as directory separators, this is easier to read than a double back-slash (`\\`).

Answer (score 4):

The approach using System will not be platform independent. I strongly recommend using [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for such tasks.

Answer (score 4):

1) include .h files:

```
#include <csystem>
```

2) write cmd:

```
system("copy c:\users\ e:\Backup\");
```

Tips: You can write everything in "  " , just like you copy directorys in cmd.

Comment: first step is : # include <csystem>

Comment: When you read the question you find that the OP has solved the task to call `system()`.